# NSFetchRequest - Fetch entity from relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have two entities: Alarm and Appointment, which have 1-to-1 relationship.

Now, I would like to retrieve the alarm for a given appointment using `NSFetchRequest`.

I tried:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:ALARM_ENTITY_NAME];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"forAppointment.objectID = %@", [appointment objectID]];
```

which throws:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath forAppointment.objectID not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Alarm id=1>'`

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"forAppointment = %@", appointment]
```

---

Using the `objectID` is only necessary if `appointment` is from a different managed object
context. In that case

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"forAppointment = %@", [appointment objectID]]
```

should work. (The right-hand side of `== %@` can be a managed object or its object ID.
You don't have to specify "objectID" in the predicate itself.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 1-1 relationship between the two (and if you've implemented `NSManagedObject` subclasses for your entities), there's no need for a fetch. Just walk the keypath:

```
Alarm *alarm = appointment.alarm;
```

Or, if you're working with primitive `NSManagedObject`

```
NSManagedObject *alarm = [appointment valueForKeyPath:@"alarm"];
```